# Facing error while running python azure function app: ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-functions, cicd

Facing below error while running python azure function app:

ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found

Also facing issue in ci pipeline 'install dependencies' task as below:
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyodbc, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
[image: Azure python function CI pipeline error screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

For me, it was fixed by updating the Azure pipeline YAML file in Azure DevOps:

```
variables:  
  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-18.04'
```

I had this issue while using `ubuntu-latest` as VM image.

Found the solution in [this blog](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/can-i-create-a-ci-cd-pipeline-to-deploy-python-function-to-azure-function-app-using-windows-self-hosted-azure-devops-agent)

Comment: Brownouts will start happening soon for Ubuntu 18.04. This answer should not be the correct one.

Comment: Agreed, when I posted this answer over a year ago it was OK but as Ubuntu 18 is end of life by April 2023 I would not recommend this anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Just added below line in my CI yaml file and it resolved the issue:
pip install wheel

before
pip install setuptools

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).